# Create Ellipsoid with input

Tags: python

I use to define of a sphere to draw an ellipsoidale, for the case of a sphere:

```
bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_uv_sphere_add(size = size, location = location)
```

For the case of an ellipsoidale, I created in this menu:
[image]

I use the lines:

```
bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_uv_sphere_add(radius_a = self.mesh.getRadius(), radius_b = self.mesh.getRadius(), radius_c = self.mesh.getRadius(), location = loc, segments = res*2, ring_count = res)


class Ellipsoid(particle) :
    """
    Ellipsoid mesh class
    """
    def __init__(self, radius_a, radius_b, radius_c) :
        """ radius_a (int), radius_b (int), radius_c (int) """
        self.radius_a = radius_a
        self.radius_b = radius_b
        self.radius_c = radius_c
```

But the problem is displayed that there is an error in the ellipsoidal definition.

Can you help me to define the ellipsoidale with input of the 3 dimensions

Answer (score 1):

If you want to create an ellipsoid, just create a sphere, scale it up or down (based on the sliders), then apply the scale